# How to update state of widgets using bloc in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have 2 widgets on a screen - A and B. There is an event
performed on widget B, on which the state of A and B should
get updated.
I have used different blocs and states for each of them and used the approach of Futures to get data from api while loading the screen.
On an event of widget B, how can I update state of both the widgets A and B without calling the api again as I can get the data from previous session and also from the response of event on widget B, it is possible to build the state on the UI itself.

Adding code:

```
    class BlocA extends Bloc<BlocAEvent,BlocAState>
    {
      BlocA():super(InitialState()){
      on<GetData>(_getBlocAData);
              }
            }
            
         void _getBlocAData(GetData event, Emitter<BlocAState>emit) 
           async{
             try {
                List<User> getDataResponse = await 
                DataService().getWidgetAData(
                    event.userid);
                
                emit(BlocALoadedState(BlocAData: getDataResponse));
               }
               catch(e){
                rethrow;
               }}
        
          class InitialState extends BlocAState{}
        
           class BlocALoadedState extends BlocAState{
             final List<User> BlocAData;
             BlocALoadedState({required this.BlocAData});
            }
        
          BlocB:
        
          abstract class BlocBStates {}
        
          class BlocBLoadedState extends BlocBStates{
            List<User> BlocBdata;
            BlocBLoadedState({required this.BlocBdata});
          }
        
          class BlocBAcceptedState extends BlocBStates{
            User user;
            BlocBAcceptedState({required this.user});
          }



Now, BlocB has event which fetches data from a different 
enter code heresource.
 
   class BlocB extends Bloc<BlocBEvent,BlocBState>
    {
      BlocB():super(InitialState()){
        on<GetData>(_getBlocBData);
        on<BlocBevent>(_onClickofaButtoninWidgetB);
      }
    }
    
    void _getBlocBData(GetData event, 
    Emitter<BlocBState>emit) 
    async{
      try {
        List<User> getDataResponse = await 
        DataService().getWidgetBData(
            event.userid);
        
        emit(BlocBLoadedState(BlocBData: getDataResponse));
       }
       catch(e){
        rethrow;
       }}

   void _onClickofaButtoninWidgetB(BlocBevent event, 
   Emitter<BlocBStates>emit) {
   User blocBEventResponse = await 
   DataService().acceptRequest( 
   event.senderId,event.receiverId)
   // From this response, I want to add this entry to bloc A's 
   // state and remove from bloc B's state
   }
```

Comment: Can you present a small portion of the code that you try to explain in text here? It sounds like A and B should share a common state, i.e. a common bloc... meaning that A and B should both have BlocBuilders that react to the same bloc, meaning that a parent to both A and B should be providing said bloc.

Comment: yes, added code. The only thing is that my blocA and blocB have different states because they get data from different sources on screen load.

Answer (score 1):

use `BlocListener`

```
BlocProvider(
  create: BlocA(),
  child: BlocListener<BlocB, StateB>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is StateBLoading) {
        context.read<BlocA>().add(EventALoading());
      } else if (state is StateBLoaded) {
        context.read<BlocA>().add(EventALoaded(state.someData));
      }
    },
    child: WidgetA();
  );
}
```

Comment: This helps. Is there a way to get state.someData from previous session(on loading the screen, I get the state with some data) and then modify it with a response I get from firing an event on WidgetB. I was thinking of using SharedPreference but not sure.

Comment: basically when an event fires on WidgetB no matter what, the BlocB should emit an new state. and what the BlocListener is doing is listening for the BlocB states and converting them to BlocA events based on what are you trying to do with them, so  if the WidgetB is using shared preference just emit BlocB state containing the response and you should access that response inside BlocListener and convert it to BlocA event which accepts that response as an argument

Comment: okay. Is there a way to keep the previous state of BlocA which can be updated with the response from BlocB which emits a new state on an event?

Comment: yes since you will handle the EventA in the BlocA you can do something like emit(state.copyWith(data: dataFromBlocB));

Comment: if you want more details share both blocs code

Comment: yes, added code. The only thing is that my blocA and blocB have different states because they get data from different sources on screen load.

Comment: I was doing something wrong in the code I just update it, try it it should work, I was add States to the BlocA it should be events not states sorry for that mistake.